# Troubleshooting Clematis

Tags: plant-health, clematis

Any way to restore this clematis to full health? I just purchased it only to realize that it needs a lot of help, but I’m not sure where to start. I can’t quite tell if it has clematis wilt, or if it’s lacking nutrients. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, S[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see what looks like nutrient deficiencies in the lower leaves that have green veins on the leaves with yellow tissue.  The top of the plant looks like clematis wilt has struck.

My clematis have had both issues at various times and I usually think "Oh, I will pull that when I get around to it" only to be surprised next spring when they pop up like new.

If you can return this plant you should do that.  If you cannot then just plant it in a sunny location where it can climb upwards and hope for the best.  Being planted in soil should resolve the nutrient deficiency and time will tell with the clematis wilt.

When you take it out of the pot examine the roots carefully.  If they are firm (and usually white) you should expect to see it next year.  Soft roots can indicate root rot.

When planting:

- remove the pot
- gently break up the bottom of the root ball where most roots should be
- place in a hole as deep as the pot and twice as wide
- no need for fertilizer or any additions to the soil
- water in
- wait for next year!

Comment: Clematis wilt is an interesting disease. I've found that cultivars with the Jackmanii cultivar in their parentage (Niobe and Bourbon, to name two) are resistant to wilt. These, along with Jackmanii, will lose one or more stems but will not die from it. Removing spent foliage as it dies seems to help reduce the incidence of disease. Other cultivars like Fleuri and Rebecca die quickly and never return. Not sure about their parentage, though. The Viticella varieties (Blue Angel, Etoile Violetta) are immune to it, so they're what I plant now. Corinne is a non-Viticella that seems to be immune.